# Kineticjs: Event listener missing after draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have created a Kineticjs scene with a scrollable background. On top of this background is a rect with an event listener attached. My question is, what could cause this event listener to not fire after I move the background and draw the scene. I don't know what it could be and I am even calling `.moveToTop()` on everything to see if I could move the shape back to the top even though I am pretty sure it still is.  So what could cause an event listener to stop firing after a draw?

Does anybody know a fix for this? I figure I could might be able to attach another event listener to the shape, but this seems unnecessary if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is some code.

```
// Here is the event listener attached to scroll bar
hscroll4.on('dragmove', updateBackgroundPos4);

// Here is code to move background
var updateBackgroundPos4 = function() {

  var hscrollPos = hscroll4.getX();
  console.log("mb4: ", mainBody4Dynamic.getX());


  mainDynamicWrapper.setX(-hscrollPos+120);  //the BG I am moving on scroll

  // my attempt at getting it to work
  dynamicLayer4.moveToTop();
  mainBody4.moveToTop();
  mainDynamicWrapper.moveToTop();
  newFolder.moveToTop();


  dynamicLayer4.draw();
  //stage4.drawHit();

};

// Here is the group which contains the rectangle
  folderGroup.on('mouseover', function() {    //---- this isn't firing after draw
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    console.log("change text");
    updateTestText();      
  });
  folderGroup.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  });
```

Edit 2: even my suggestion does not work. Adding the event listener back does not make it clickable again :(

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Or at least show some code?

Comment: I attached some code. I would have to heavily modify the code to create a fiddle so I hope I attached enough.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got it! I found a thread which said to create an dragend event on the scrollbar then  call `layer.moveToTop()` and `layer.draw()`. So putting it in dragmove was not enough for the program to register click events. The reasoning behind this was:

"When you use a drag event, KineticJS create a temporary layer on top as a result of which your events where not getting registered after the dragmove."

Here is the thread if anybody is interested:

[LINK TO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676906/events-are-lost-after-moving-layer-from-within-a-dragmove-callback)